# R - How to add id or class attribute to SVG paths created?

Tags: r, svg, plot, attributes

I'm using R to generate SVG files. Essentially, we take our data and use the `plot()` function to create the paths we need in an SVG. However, I also want to be able to interact with these SVG paths and if I could select them based on an id or class, I could separate the paths from all the rest. Our data file has the information for each different area, but it would be nice if we could add an attribute to the SVG paths created so we can select them separately when we upload it to the web.

If necessary, here's a tidbit of code for generating the SVG file

```
svg(filename = "violentCrime.svg", width = 7, height = 10)
plot(cleanedData$Latitude[which(generalized.crime.type == "violent crime")]~-cleanedData$Longitude[which(generalized.crime.type == "violent crime")], 
     pch = 20, ylim=c(47.47,47.73), xlim=c(-122.43,-122.23),
     xlab="", ylab="", xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', bty = 'n', col=alpha("red", .1))
plot(beat.KML2, border="black", add=T)
```

**Is there a way to add ids or attributes in general to the paths created? Are there any packages that help with this?**

Comment: check out the `gridSVG` package?

Comment: Ahh I see the `grid.garnish` function. I'll give that a whirl and get back to you.

Comment: @aug Note that `grid.garnish` is specific to graphics built on the `grid` library. The default `plot` function is not such a function.

Comment: Sorry I never got a chance to get back on this. Due to time constraints, I simply manually added the classes to the svg paths but I do want to explore this when I have time.